# stop JS animation function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script, I would like it it stop moving after the last movement of the animation, instead it just flickers/repeats. I've tried adding a .stop but I'm not having much luck:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).scroll( function() {  
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {  
       loadDiv();  
    }  
});  
function loadDiv() {  
    $('#container-holder').fadeIn('slow', function() {  
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);  
        $('#container, #imagetest1').fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '0'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-78px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-156px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-234px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-312px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
    });  
}  
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
#background {
width: 200px;
height: 1000px;
border: 1px solid #999;
}
#container-holder {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid #999;
visibility: visible;
margin-top: 100px;
}
#container {
width: 160px;
height: 160px;
background-color: #333f;
border: 1px solid #333f;
}
#imagetest1 {
width: 162px;
height: 390px;
background-image: url('http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz40/mjl-admin/rainbow.jpg');
border: 1px solid green;
}
#image-container {
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
}
#image1 {
width: 165px;
height: 78px;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="background">
<div id="container-holder">
<div id="container">
    <div id="image1"><div id="imagetest1"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fatfrank44/bwbEu/9/

Comment: Is there any reason for those `duration: 0`? And you might want to try chaining all of them together.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I didn't know you can write so much for doing so 'less'...

Comment: You can use [.stop(true, true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), Its very hard to understand what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation is running over and over because it's restarted once for every time the `window.scroll` event is triggered.

If you want the animation to happen exactly once, you can use [`.one('scroll')`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to attach the event and then dispose of it immediately:

```
$(window).one('scroll',function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
        loadDiv();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/nRr2j/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for, but: http://jsfiddle.net/bwbEu/10/

```
$(window).scroll( function() {  
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {  
       loadDiv();  
    }  
});  
function loadDiv() {  
    $('#image1').fadeIn('slow', function() {  
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '0'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-78px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-156px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-234px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-312px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
    });  
}
```

and:

```
#image1 {
width: 165px;
height: 78px;
background-color: #fff;
overflow: hidden;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Joris!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm understanding your question correctly...
JofryHS makes a good point, to chain all of them together, which should be done either way for cleaner code - and this may help us better understand what you're trying to do. I think you can also make the animation stop by incrementing a variable after each animation, then check if that variable is a certain number before calling loadDiv() again.

```
var checkIterate = 0;

$(window).scroll( function() {  
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 && checkIterate < 5) {  
          loadDiv();  
     }  
});  
function loadDiv() {  
    $('#image1').fadeIn('slow', function() {  
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '0'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-78px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-156px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-234px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        $('#imagetest1').delay(30).animate({'margin-top': '-312px'}, {duration:0, queue:true});
        checkIterate = 5;
    });  
}
```

And when just make it so that checkIterate is set back to 0 when the page scrolls down again (or when scrollTop increases